# How can I pass a parameter into a Backbone.js view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to pass a parameter into a Backbone.js view, but I'm having trouble doing it.

I have a Backbone view as follows:

```
var DataTypesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events:{
        'click .datatype': 'add'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log(this.magic);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log('printing template');
        console.log(this.templateString);

                    etc.
}});
```

Later, I crate the view as follows:

```
        dataTypesView = new DataTypesView({magic:true,el:$('#dataViewSpace'),templateString:'#template'});
```

It doesn't work. What I don't understand is why the `el` works just fine (and I can access it using jquery with `this.$el.`), yet `this.magic` and `this.templateString` are both undefined...

Is there any way that I can pass a parameter into a view in the way I'm trying to above?

On a related note - is there any way I can pass the render function in? I initially tried passing a render function in (and removing it from the backbone view class), but when that didn't work I tried passing in simple datatypes instead... I'm assuming that whatever needs to be done to pass in a parameter for my first question will work for passing in a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### EDIT - apparently this answer doesn't work in newer versions of Backbone.

I figured it out! T'was pretty straightforward... All it took was a quick check of the Backbone.js documentation... should have done that first.

The following parameters when passed in are automatically assigned to the view (AKA you can access them with `this.variableName`): model, collection, el, id, className, tagName and attributes

ALL OTHER VARIABLES can be accessed with `this.options.variableName`.

From my example above, I can get access to `magic` by using `this.options.magic`, instead of `this.magic`.

Yay!

Comment: This doesnt work for me. There is no options object in the view at all.

Answer (score 2):

stuff that is not unique to the framwork goes to options

look in

`this.options.magic`

Comment: hey lior - if you make your answer a little more informative (AKA include the extra info that I've included in my answer), then I'll accept your answer. Otherwise, I'll accept my own once I am able to.

Answer (score 2):

In more recent version of Backbone (mine is 1.1.2) you can copy View constructor options this way:

```
initialize: function(options) {
  _.extend(this, _.pick(options, 'several', 'specific', 'options'));
}
```

Credits goes to [this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1383) github issue.